# Use existing memory to store result of temporary variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Matrix class with a dynamically allocated array member variable. This class has a static function with the following signature:

```
static Matrix addMatrices(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);
```

Let's say I have 3 matrices as below:

```
Matrix a;
Matrix b;
Matrix c;
```

Imagine later in my code, I would like to add matrices *a* and *b* together, and store the result in matrix *c*:

```
c = Matrix::addMatrices(a, b);
```

My issue with this is that, in calling *Matrix::addMatrices()*, the compiler has to create a **temporary variable** to store the result of *Matrix::addMatrices(a, b)*. Since this involves a dynamic heap allocation, this could prove costly in lengthy, repetitive calculations where the array inside the matrix is large.

This could, however, be avoided if one were to define the above function like so:

```
static void addMatrices(Matrix& result, const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);
```

Here, one could simply pass in matrix *c*'s address and store the result of *a + b* directly in the elements of *c*, avoiding an unnecessary heap allocation.

My question is, is there a way for you to somehow use the existing memory of matrix *c* to store the result of *a + b* using the first function method?

Note that this is not a question about move semantics, as move assignment operator overloading uses the dynamically allocated memory in the temporary variable *a + b* for the members of *c*, instead of the other way around.

Thanks!

Comment: `Matrix a();` declares a function named `a` taking no parameters and returning `Matrix`. It doesn't define a variable of type `Matrix`.

Comment: Implement efficient move operations for your `Matrix` class, and then `c = Matrix::addMatrices(a, b);` wouldn't need to involve a copy, nor unnecessary heap allocations.

Comment: You could use [expression template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) techniques. E.g. `Matrix::addMatrices(a, b)` would not actually perform the addition, but would return an object of a helper class, say `Adder`, that stores pointers to `a` and `b`. Then you would implement an assignment operator `Matrix::operator=(Adder adder)` that would call `realAdd(this, adder.a, adder.b)` which would do the actual addition into existing storage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks a lot! Will definitely give this a try.